# How do I get my Jewels/Gems out of my weapon?

Tags: diablo-ii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you recover socketed gems/runes from an item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33289/how-do-you-recover-socketed-gems-runes-from-an-item)

Aside from playing Diablo 3 for countless hours of the day, I can honestly say that I never beat Diablo 2. In fact, I decided to start playing it again to see if I could beat the ol' game. Seeing as I didn't play much of D2 before I didn't get to experience the whole thing. **How do I remove a jewel or a gem from a socketed item?** Is there a jeweler in D2 like there is in D3?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this formula page](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/cube.shtml#unsocket) you may use the Horodric Cube recipe of combining your socketed item with 1 Hel Rune and 1 Scroll of Town Portal to destroy the gems inside and leave fresh sockets. The Cube also replaces the Jeweler's gem combining function: combining three gems of the same type and quality (other than Perfect) promotes it one level.

Comment: Note that the gems will be destroyed in this example, not returned to inventory